# grails: hosting maven-style plugins on a plain http server (s3)

Tags: maven, grails, amazon-s3

I'm using `release:3.0` and `maven-s3-wagon` to publish a grails plugin to my own s3 repo. The s3 repo has "public read for all" and is website-enabled. The problem is, I can't figure out how to configure `BuildConfig.groovy` in my project to use this plugin.

Hosting on s3 with Maven seems to be possible, I found a few publishing howtos: [1](http://blog.brickcitylabs.com/2012/02/hosting-maven-repository-on-amazons-s3.html) [2](http://build-doctor.com/2011/10/10/repository-thats-not-a-repository/), and a few that are fairly similar: [1](http://stuartsierra.com/2009/09/08/run-your-own-maven-repository) [2](http://blog.glassdiary.com/post/65190237091/hosting-your-own-maven-repository-on-github-or) [3](http://cemerick.com/2010/08/24/hosting-maven-repos-on-github/) [4](https://code.google.com/p/peter-lavalle/wiki/MavenOnDropBox). There's also [this slick javascript-based directory browser](http://jayunit100.blogspot.com/2014/01/ajax-maven-s3-lightweight-maven.html), but I think that is optional and only for human usage. There's also the [possibility of using an ivy resolver](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/url.html), though my grails resolver is configured to maven.

Given all that, I can't figure out why my use of this plugin fails. Here's what I have in my `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
  repositories {
    mavenRepo "http://mybucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
  }
  plugins {
    compile 'com.mydomain:myplugin:0.4'
  }
}
```

And here's what "s3 list recursive" looks like for `mybucket`:

```
2014-03-20 15:40:06        507 com/mydomain/myplugin/0.4/myplugin-0.4-plugin.xml
2014-03-20 15:40:06         32 com/mydomain/myplugin/0.4/myplugin-0.4-plugin.xml.md5
2014-03-20 15:40:07         40 com/mydomain/myplugin/0.4/myplugin-0.4-plugin.xml.sha1
2014-03-20 15:39:56      66482 com/mydomain/myplugin/0.4/myplugin-0.4.grails-plugin
2014-03-20 15:39:57         32 com/mydomain/myplugin/0.4/myplugin-0.4.grails-plugin.md5
2014-03-20 15:39:58         40 com/mydomain/myplugin/0.4/myplugin-0.4.grails-plugin.sha1
2014-03-20 15:40:03       8893 com/mydomain/myplugin/0.4/myplugin-0.4.pom
2014-03-20 15:40:04         32 com/mydomain/myplugin/0.4/myplugin-0.4.pom.md5
2014-03-20 15:40:04         40 com/mydomain/myplugin/0.4/myplugin-0.4.pom.sha1
2014-03-20 15:40:01        354 com/mydomain/myplugin/maven-metadata.xml
2014-03-20 15:40:01         32 com/mydomain/myplugin/maven-metadata.xml.md5
2014-03-20 15:40:02         40 com/mydomain/myplugin/maven-metadata.xml.sha1
2014-03-20 15:37:15         13 index.html
```

Note index.html is a simple "hello world".

When I run `grails dependency-report` or `grails run-app`, I get failures on my plugin since it doesn't exist elsewhere. Here's a sample from `dependency-report`:

```
| Error Could not find artifact com.mydomain:myplugin:zip:0.4 in mybucket_s3-website-us-east-1_amazonaws_com (http://mybucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com) (scope: test) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

I wish the grails resolution would show the exact URL it is trying to fetch. But what am I missing to make this work? Is there a "generic" `pom.xml` or other root file?

Comment: Can you browse to http://mybucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com and see your artefacts there? Is the URL to the artefact http://mybucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/com/mydomain/myplugin/0.4 ? The reason I ask is because our repo has a `/repository/com/mydomain` path and you might be missing a URL prefix in the `mavenRepo` entry? EDIT: you may have to use wget from the server where grails is running, if the URLs are not public

Comment: @nickdos urls are public. They aren't browsable from the root, there's no directory listings or anything. But yes, the com/mydomain/.. paths work to access it. No prefix. I have a theory it is because they aren't zipped- can you see if your private repo artifacts are zipped?

Comment: Plugin artifacts are unusual in that they have to be zipped (yes mine are zipped). Grails does this for you when you run `grails maven-deploy` - see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#mavendeploy

Comment: that's how I deployed, with `maven-deploy`. I have to manually upload the zip and sha1 to make them appear. So there are two things that could be wrong- I'm failing to upload it to the correct spot, or my resolver is wrong. How do you run your resolver, (`mavenRepo` or `URLResolver` maybe?), in buildconfig to actually use it? And is `dependency.resolver = "maven"`?

Comment: FWIW, just tried putting the zip in my main project's `lib` folder and it isn't working. Wondering if I have a larger problem?